# Agregar una suma a estos Set de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo estos dos Set de datos los cuales necesito Sumar los valores cuando son Credito o debito. de no ser posible tmb tendria la opcion de insertarlos en una tabla temporal, el problema es que me tira error cuando intento hacer cualquiera de las dos cosas:S alguien me ayuda?

```
select 
        roundId, 
        TransactionType,
        CreditAmount,
        DebitAmount
    from 
        TABLA1 t with (nolock)
    where 
        TransactionType = 'Credit' and
        not exists 
            ( 
            select 1 
            from 
                TABLA1 tt  with (nolock)
            where
                t.roundId = tt.roundId and
                tt.TransactionType = 'Debit'
            )



select 
        roundId, 
        TransactionType,
        CreditAmount,
        DebitAmount
    from 
        TABLA1 t with (nolock)
    where 
        TransactionType = 'Debit' and
        not exists 
            ( 
            select 1 
            from 
                TABLA1 tt  with (nolock)
            where
                t.roundId = tt.roundId and
                tt.TransactionType = 'Credit' 
            )
```

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es el saldo final de la cuenta?

Comment: no, el tema es el siguiente, con esa query separo las transacciones de tipo credito y debito que quedaron 'huerfanas' de una tabla. eso esta hecho , ahora el problema es poder sumar todas las que son credit por un lado y todas las debit por otro para tener un registro de cuanto dinero quedo dando vueltas

Comment: Te doy un poco mas de contexto, es un sistema de apuestas el cual por cada apuesta(debit) devuelve un valor de ganancia(credit) el problema es que no siempre es asi, y quedan muchas solo con credit o debit y necesito saber la plata que significa esa perdida, para eso agarre de una tabla y busque cada registro que del typeTransacction no tenga un emparejamiento siendo un credit en un debit o visceversa, ahora necesito la suma total

Comment: ¿No lo podrías resolver con un `group by`, así: `select roundId, sum(isnull(CreditAmount,0)) - isnull(sum(DebitAmount,0)) from TABLA1 t group by roundId`?